# glfw no close button

Tags: graphics, window-buttons, apic

With native programs everything works as expected, but when try to run a basic program using the glfw library I get a window without buttons. How to enable them?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Your question is not answerable without more information. Which distro and version of Linux are you using? How did you install "g**l**fw"? Do you mean g**u**fw? If so how did you install it? Please take a screenshot of the app and [add it to your question along with all the other information](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1507634/edit).

Comment: Do you have these packages installed: libglfw3 libglfw3-dev libglfw3-wayland?